# Download files inside div element using selenium - Python

Tags: python, selenium

I would like to use selenium in python to download files inside `div` element(no of files are dynamic inside div).I have a list of file names.

HTML Contents:

```
<div _ngcontent-c16="" class="ng-star-inserted">
<!---->
<!---->
    <div _ngcontent-c16="" class="documents ng-star-inserted">
        <div _ngcontent-c16="" class="row">
            <div _ngcontent-c16="" class="col-12">
            <button _ngcontent-c16="" class="btn btn-primary btn-block card-button" type="button" aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-2" cdk-describedby-host="" style="touch-action: none; user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
            <span _ngcontent-c16="" class="halflings halflings-download-alt">
            </span> example.zip 
            </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-c16="" class="documents ng-star-inserted">
        <div _ngcontent-c16="" class="row">
            <div _ngcontent-c16="" class="col-12">
            <button _ngcontent-c16="" class="btn btn-primary btn-block card-button" type="button" aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-2" cdk-describedby-host="" style="touch-action: none; user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
            <span _ngcontent-c16="" class="halflings halflings-download-alt">
            </span> example2.zip 
            </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am tried using...

```
xpath = "/html/body/app-root/div/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/div/div/app-application-detail/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/button"
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
```

I am tried using file name, xpath but not able to click and download file.
Any solution ?

Comment: First of all, avoid that xpath,  try with "//div[@class='ng-star-inserted']//div[@class='row']/button". Second post of your python code to check iteration

Comment: whats error you are getting

Comment: @Shubham Jain I ma getting following error ```no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[span[contains(text(), 'example.zip')]]"}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your HTML sample, it looks like the `example.zip` text is contained in the `button` element itself. Because there are multiple buttons, you should query on the `example.zip` text for the button. I would invoke a WebDriverWait and use a relative XPath like this:

```
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'example.zip')]")))
button.click()
```

If that does not work, you could try running Javascript to click the button instead:

```
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'example.zip')]")))

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

Comment: I am tried but I am getting following error ```no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[span[contains(text(), 'example.zip')]]"}```

Comment: @SurajM I've updated my example to invoke a WebDriverWait on the button before clicking it, which may help. If this does not solve your issue, I recommend posting a link to the page you are automating, or the full page HTML, so we can look and see if there are any other elements obscuring the button.

Comment: The code is able to find the element but after click action nothing is happens. Manually when I click the file is downloaded.

Comment: @SurajM I've updated my answer to try a different XPath, and also attempt a Javascript click to see if we can click the element that way. Let me know if this works for you.